# time_to_sec of mysql equivalent in hibernate HQL

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there any method in hibernate HQL which has the same functionality as `TIME_TO_SEC` in a MySQL database.

Asking this because I want to use this HQL query even in my Oracle Database:

```
"select count(log) from Entry log where time_to_sec(lclTime) between '"
             + timeInSeconds + "' and '" + nextHour + "
```

I have to make this query executable in both Oracle and MySQL databases using hibernate HQL.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using database-specific functions (Native MySQL Queries) it will not work when you change your database  to Oracle. I think the sensible fix is to use HQL. I found your query is not portable either way as you have written.

Fix:
 1. Migrate MySQL Time Data type to Oracle Date data type.
 2. Change your Entity field to java.sql.Date type.

IF you face any issue then try to use Hibernate User Type to Map it.

User Type data type help a lot in this case.